# How to know jetpack compose material 3 repo

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hi guys i get the issues of material design for jetpack compose i wanna to know where it's repo i'm strugling to find it on github just found for material component not for compose

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for any of these? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3 / https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary / https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.material3/material3 / https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3/

Comment: Thanks a lot, i found contributing page thanks

Comment: this mean we just allow to constribute for these only?

The list of folders that can be contributed to, using the GitHub repository are:

androidx
  -- activity
  -- appcompat
  -- biometric
  -- compose/compiler
  -- compose/runtime
  -- core
  -- datastore
  -- fragment
  -- lifecycle
  -- navigation
  -- paging
  -- room
  -- work

Answer (score 0):

The [`material3`](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/compose/material3) library is included in this [`androidx`](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/compose/material3) repository.

If you want to contribute, note however the the information in the [Readme.md](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/README.md):

> Note: The contributions workflow via GitHub is currently experimental - only contributions to the following projects are being accepted at this time:
>
> - Activity
> - AppCompat
> - Biometric
> - Collection
> - Compose Compiler
> - Compose Runtime
> - Core
> - DataStore
> - Fragment
> - Lifecycle
> - Navigation
> - Paging
> - Room
> - WorkManager

So currently, no pull requests for `androidx/compose/material3` will be accepted.